# application crushes after executing stop command of QTimer

Tags: qt

I wrote a simple code in which I declared a QTimer function and wrote a bunch of commands in it then in another function i used the command timer->stop() (in order to stop and reset the timer) which is making my program crush. I don't know if I can't use it Outside the Timer function... a little view of my code:

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Timer()));
timer->start(2000);
```

This is how i set up my Timer

```
    void Monitor::on_actionReset_triggered()
{
    timer->stop();
    timer->setInterval(0);
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to reset it in another function

Comment: Looks like you either deleted the timer or didn't create it yet. Why are you making the timer a pointer to begin with? Using pointers creates this kind of problem. Try making it a value data member of the class and without a parent.

Comment: I did create my timer but didn't post it... Ok i'll try your suggestion thank you for your reply.

Comment: @NikosC. actually it did work thank you for the tip

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].